# Meaning of こうまでも and use of 掛ける

Tags: meaning

> **こうまでも**プレッシャーを掛けられるとは

I don't understand how こうまでも works here.

Does プレッシャーを掛ける mean "to put pressure on"? I'm trying to translate 掛ける individually here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「こうまでも」 means "to *this* extent".  「こう」 is used emphatically here.

> Does プレッシャーを掛{か}ける mean "to put pressure on"?

Yes, it does.  It would need to be remembered as a set phrase.  Otherwise, one would probably not be able to come up with 「掛ける」if one were translating word for word from English.

Answer (score 0):

So 掛ける means to multiply. In the context of the sentence you mentioned I'm going to assume that the phrase is the Japanese equivalent of "the pressure is increasing" as in pressure to perform well or something like that. I'm not certain about the rest of the sentence unfortunately, so maybe someone else can chime in.

Answer (score 0):

プレッシャーを掛ける does mean 'to put pressure on'. こうまでも is used when said pressure was more than you expected, especially when you are not sure if you can handle the pressure.
In general, it could be used in many more sentences. For example, if you knew weather was going to be bad but if weather got much worse than you expected, you would say こうまでも天気が悪くなるとは思わなかった。